# xerox machine deployed screen - html dropdown is flickering on tab selection

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asmx, xerox

A simple page design was done with html and javascript. It has some dropdown controls. the application was deployed on xerox machine screen. On the machine screen, when the user tab select the dropdown, it is not opening properly. sometimes it is flickering i.e, it is opening, but before select any item it is closing, then again opening. This blink happening multiple times. After 4 to 5 times, it is opening properly, then only we are able to select the item. What could be the reason?

On tab selection it should open once and should wait for selection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.